# Как прописать modrewrite?

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite

Здравствуйте.

Хочу чтобы `site.ru/kontakty/` выглядел как `site.ru/contacts.html`

Как надо прописать `modrewrite`?

`RewriteRule ^/kontakty/$ contacts.html` - не выходит.

Повесили сайт на `cms`, но важно сохранить ссылки, заказчик настаивает, мол важно для `сео`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте данную **[Статью](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**, это вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Переведите слова "выглядел как". Пользователь по какому URL заходит, /kontakty/? Тогда:

```
RewriteRule ^kontakty/$ /contacts.html
```